# Transform a form array data to Json in Angular and Typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, forms, typescript

I've a form and when i submit it with ng-submit, i've a array of fields.
I want to post it and calling a rest WS.
But in my angular ts controller, i don't know how i can mapping the data and convert them in the final object template.

Have you a example how i can do that ? I don't find anything.
As i understand, i have to declared and create a object with the final structure of the JSON but i don't know how i can mapping all this stuff.

What's the best way to post a angular form with some fields in a another json template ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly send your form data to your controller in object form. 
You should declare an empty object on your controller `$scope.data = {};`.
In your html form you have:

```
<form ng-submit="send_data(data)">
  <input type="text" ng-model="data.input1">
  <input type="text" ng-model="data.input2">
  <button type="submit">
</form>
```

In this way, your data is already an object. 
Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Yes. I've write a bad explaination. I get my object in my typescript controller but i don't How i can transform the template with typescript and bind the data.